# Connect b2c to b2c

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I can link any AAD to my b2c (using app registration or direct federation using saml2). Is it possible to link b2c to b2c? My goal is to authenticate user whos' organization domain is not handled by my b2c, but external b2c can handle it. So, external b2c will act like external IDP (identity provider). Any docs on this integration?

Comment: Yeah it is possible since AAD B2C is an OpenID Connect identity provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the documentation on [Microsoft learn - Azure AD B2C Identity Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-b2c?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).

This federation can only be setup with OIDC. SAML federation between B2C to B2C is not supported.